# Как передать функцию в метод?

Tags: c++

У меня есть такая функция

```
void VideoRender::timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval) {
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true) {
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
        }
    }).detach();
}
```

Есть вот такой метод который я передаю в эту функцию

```
void VideoRender::loadNewData() {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "LoadPLY3 ::: %s", "HERE");
}
```

И вот так я это все вызываю

```
timer_start(loadNewData, 1000);
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку при компиляции

> 25: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?

Что делаю не так?

Comment: `loadNewData` принимает 1 аргумент, а требуется функция, принимающая 0 аргументов

Comment: Не `static` методы первым аргументом принимают указатель на объект класса - `this`.

Comment: @VTT добавил `void` в скобки метода вот так `void  loadNewData(void);` , но не помогло...

Comment: @RiotBr3aker где принимают? Не понял, вот тут нужно не так присать `timer_start(loadNewData, 1000);` , а так `timer_start(this, 1000);` ?

Comment: это функция по-прежнему будет принимать 1 аргумент - `this`

Comment: Прошу меня извинить, выразился не совсем верно, вызов метода и вызов функции - это немного "разные" вещи. Внутри методы - это функции с первым аргументом в виде указателя на вызывающий метод объект, но при этом просто так вручную вы туда this передать не сможете. Есть несколько решений - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected

Comment: @VTT я не пойму. Куда она его принимает ? Как сделать, что она его не принимала?

Comment: Никак не сделать. Нестатический метод класса всегда принимает скрытый параметр `this`. Вам действительно нужен именно нестатический метод класса???

Answer (score 3):

Нарисуйте статическую функцию и отдайте её.

```
class VideoRender{
..
static void st_loadNewData(VideoRender & me){me.loadNewData();}
..
};

timer_start(VideoRender::st_loadNewData, 1000);
```